# I can't get my final textview to show up horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make my final TextView show directly under the Horizontal scroll view and to the left of my relative view. What am I doing wrong? When I add in layout_below `@+id/discussionHorScrollView` it doesn't work either.

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/discussionHorScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scrollViewQuestion"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/discussionScrollBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/FullResponseAvatar"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below ="@id/discussionHorScrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
    <MvxImageView
        android:id="@+id/ResponseAavatar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl QuickResponse.AvatarUrl; DefaultImagePath 'res:icon_user'" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/discussion_image_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDiscussionTitle"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/FullResponseAvatar"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/FullResponseAvatar"
        android:textColor="@color/discussion_cell_title_text"
        local:MvxBind="Text QuickResponse.FullName" />
```

EDIT: My Full View (added some returns to demo where i am working)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainmenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgFullDiscussionAvatar"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <MvxImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgDiscussionAvatar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            local:MvxBind="ImageUrl QuickResponse.Question.AvatarUrl; DefaultImagePath 'res:icon_user'" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/discussion_image_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDiscussionTitle"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgFullDiscussionAvatar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgFullDiscussionAvatar"
        android:textColor="@color/discussion_cell_title_text"
        local:MvxBind="Text ModFullName" />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewQuestion"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgFullDiscussionAvatar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgFullDiscussionAvatar"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtDiscussionTitle">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDiscussionText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textDirection="locale"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/discussion_cell_content_text"
            local:MvxBind="Text QuickResponse.Question.Body" />
    </ScrollView>
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/discussionHorScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scrollViewQuestion"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/discussionScrollBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>



  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/FullResponseAvatar"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below ="@id/discussionHorScrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
    <MvxImageView
        android:id="@+id/ResponseAavatar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl QuickResponse.AvatarUrl; DefaultImagePath 'res:icon_user'" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/discussion_image_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDiscussionTitle"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/FullResponseAvatar"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/FullResponseAvatar"
        android:textColor="@color/discussion_cell_title_text"
        local:MvxBind="Text QuickResponse.FullName" />




  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListHeader"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_header"
        android:textColor="@color/discussion_cell_content_text"
        android:layout_below="@id/FullResponseAvatar"
        local:MvxBind="Text QuickResponse.ResponseTypeId, Converter=AnswerHeader" />
    <MvxListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtListHeader"
        android:id="@+id/textAnswersListView"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource TextAnswersList" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/media_post_bar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/response_post_bar"
        android:background="@drawable/user_media_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPaperClip"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_paperclip" />
        <MvxImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgPaperClip"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgPaperClip" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTrash"
            android:layout_width="14dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_trashcan" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/response_post_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/responsebar_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgResponseCamera"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_camera" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnResponsePost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@color/responsebar_background_transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/responsebar_content"
            local:MvxBind="Click PostCommand" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtResponseText"
            android:textDirection="locale"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgResponseCamera"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnResponsePost"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgResponseCamera"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnResponsePost"
            android:background="@drawable/responsebar_edittext"
            android:textColor="@color/responsebar_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/responsebar_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dip"
            local:MvxBind="Text CommentText" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you have a parent view for all the three views you put there? also you should use match_parent instead of fill_parent

Comment: yeah its all inside of a relative layout

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/discussionHorScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scrollViewQuestion"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/discussionScrollBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/FullResponseAvatar"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below ="@id/discussionHorScrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
    <MvxImageView
        android:id="@+id/ResponseAavatar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl QuickResponse.AvatarUrl; DefaultImagePath 'res:icon_user'" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/discussion_image_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDiscussionTitle"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/FullResponseAvatar"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/FullResponseAvatar"
        android:textColor="@color/discussion_cell_title_text"
        local:MvxBind="Text QuickResponse.FullName" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That doesn't work either everything shifts to the very top. I will edit the above to show my whole view.